# legend not displayed for radar Angular-chart.js

Tags: angularjs, chart.js, angular-chart, angular-chartist.js

I'm trying to create a radar chart using angular-chart js and chartjs 2.1.
I was able to display the graph but not the legend.
would you help me to display it.
here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/09WSHD?p=preview) for what I've done

```
<canvas id="area" class="chart chart-radar" chart-data="data"
                  chart-labels="labels" chart-options="options" chart-legend = "true"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't add series in your canvas tag, [edited plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BPdEKDi4a5EWEOfyzhWO?p=preview).

```
<canvas id="area" class="chart chart-radar" chart-data="data"
                  chart-labels="labels" chart-options="options" chart-series="series" chart-legend = "true"></canvas>
```